# What are the Netsuite EU sandbox URLs?

Tags: netsuite, sandbox, suitescript

We used to access Netsuite restlets on rest.sandbox.netsuite.com. I have recently come back to a project and these no longer work. Login into the sandbox has also been updated so EU users now switch to a sandbox role instead, this updates the URL to include eu1.

According to: https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/65712/kw/sandbox%20restlet

I believe that requests should be made against rest.eu1.netsuite.com/ for sandbox/preview data. However updates to Restlets in the sandbox account do not appear to be reflected in the request responses.

What am I missing? I've been scouring the Netsuite docs but have come up blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer. You need to append _SB1 SB2 etc onto the account id in the request auth header. I'm not sure how this would work for oAuth but I guess I'll cross that bridge later...

https://system.eu2.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4609939018.html

Account ID Numbering Conventions for EU Sandbox

In NA sandboxes, there is a primary sandbox and there might be a secondary sandbox, or secondary sandboxes. The account ID for the primary sandbox is the same as the account ID of the production account. Secondary sandboxes might, or might not, have the same account ID as the production account, appended with _SB2, _SB3, and so on. (For more information, see Primary Sandbox and Secondary Sandboxes.)

In EU sandboxes, there is no concept of a primary sandbox; all EU sandboxes are secondary sandboxes. The account ID is always the same as the account ID for your production account, appended with _SB1, _SB2, _SB3, and so on.

For example:

Production account ID: 123456
EU sandbox account ID: 123456_SB1
EU sandbox account ID: 123456_SB2
EU sandbox account ID: 123456_SB3

Answer (score 1):

NetSuite recently opened at least one new data center and moved some of their customer accounts around.  Our domain changed from `rest.netsuite.com` to `rest.na3.netsuite.com`.  Our sandbox URLs have NOT changed.

NetSuite recommends avoiding statically defined URLs  and they provide two ways to dynamically discover the various URLs for an accounting using a `getDataCenterUrls()` request.

There are both SOAP and REST(-like) ways to get this information.  You can read about these processes in the [documentation here](https://system.na3.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_n3494684.html).  They provide examples in both Java and C#.  These examples work for sandbox URLs as well if you point the initial request to `https://rest.sandbox.netsuite.com/rest/roles`.

In the 2017.2 upgrade, NetSuite is introducing Account-Specific Domains which will not change regardless of the data center in which a customer account is located.  These will look like `123456.restlets.api.netsuite.com`.  See the [2017.2 Release Notes](https://system.na3.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/PDF/ReleaseNotes_2017.2.0.pdf) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Mike.

On the link I provided there is a notification area which contains the following text:
 
"Important Users access an EU sandbox through their production URL. It is not necessary to enter a URL to go to an EU sandbox. Users access an EU sandbox by switching from a production role to a sandbox role."

Which leaves me thinking that things are a bit different for those of us in the EU. I'll have another go with getDataCenterUrls, I didn't make much progress with that prior to my question.